# Inexchangeability of a random graph drawn from a graphon model

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that $G_n$ is a $n$-node random graph drawn from a [graphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphon) model, in which the graphon is $g:[0,1]^2\rightarrow[0,1]$. A random graph is exchangeable if its distribution is invariant under every permutation of its nodes. Show that $G_n$ is exchangeable.

Find the degree distribution $\mathbb P(D_i=m)$ for $m=0,\dots,n-1$ where $D_i$ is the degree of node $i$.

Not sure how to answer these two questions. I'm thinking the degree distribution should be binomial, but I don't know how to determine the edge probability.

Comment: The distribution is not necessarily binomial, depending on the graphon. Suppose for example that $$g(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 & x < \frac12 \text{ or } y < \frac12 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Then $D_i$ is a mixture distribution: it is $\textit{Binomial}(n-1, \frac12)$ half the time, and the constant $n-1$ the rest of the time.

Comment: Thank you for the example. That is quite interesting.